# How to Insert and get data from Sql

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

i am trying to add my Todo formm to the sql but i get a null error,
 i tested with printout and the value are there.
and my update grid also not showing me nothing in the grid i tested the command in the service and seems to show but the grid not showing me.
can you assist me on this ? thank you.
my code is :
**Todo.java**

```
package com.packagename.myapp.spring;


import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

public class Todo {
    private  long userID;
    private String taskstatus;
    private long ID;
    private long customerID;
    private long descriptionID;
    private String taskStatus;
    private String Subject;
    private LocalDate Dudate;

    public Todo() // Def Ctor
    {

    }
 public Todo (String taskstatus,LocalDate dudate,String subject,long customerid){

     this.customerID= customerid;
     this.Subject = subject;
     this.Dudate = dudate;
     this.taskstatus = taskstatus;
 }
    public Todo(long id, long customerid, long descriptionid, String task) { // Ctor all
        this.ID=id;
        this.customerID=customerid;
        this.descriptionID=descriptionid;
        this.taskStatus=task;

    }

    public long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public long getDescriptionID() {
        return descriptionID;
    }

    public void setDescriptionID(long descriptionID) {
        this.descriptionID = descriptionID;
    }

    public String getTaskStatus() {
        return taskStatus;
    }

    public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
        this.taskStatus = taskStatus;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return Subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.Subject = subject;
    }

    public LocalDate getDudate() {
        return Dudate;
    }

    public void setDudate(LocalDate dudate) {
        this.Dudate = dudate;
    }

    public long getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(long customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }
}
```

**TodoView.java**

```
@Route(value = NAV,layout = MainView.class)
public class TodoView extends Composite<Div> {
    public static final String NAV = "todo";
    public Todo todo = new Todo();
    private Grid<Todo> todogrid = new Grid<>(Todo.class);
    private Binder<Todo> binder = new Binder<>(Todo.class);
    private TodoService service ;
    private  Button addButton = new Button("Save", e -> {
        try {
            binder.writeBean(todo);
           // System.out.println(todo.getCustomerID());
          //  System.out.println(todo.getTaskStatus());
          //  System.out.println(todo.getDudate());
          //  System.out.println(todo.getSubject());
            saveTodo();
           // updateGrid();
            binder.readBean(new Todo());
        } catch (ValidationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    public TodoView(){

        //Layouts//
        HorizontalLayout todofields = new HorizontalLayout();
        VerticalLayout todoList = new VerticalLayout();
        HorizontalLayout subjects = new HorizontalLayout();
        todogrid.addThemeNames("no-border","no-row-borders","row-strips");
        GridMultiSelectionModel<Todo> selectionModel = (GridMultiSelectionModel<Todo>) todogrid
                .setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.MULTI);
        selectionModel.selectAll();


        //Layouts//



        //Fields//
        ComboBox<String> taskstatus = new ComboBox<>("TaskStatus:");
        taskstatus.setItems("Completed","OnProgress","Cancelled");
        TextField subject = new TextField();
        subject.setLabel("נושא:");
        TextField customerid = new TextField();
        customerid.setLabel("שם הלקוח:");
        DatePicker dudate = new DatePicker();
        dudate.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        dudate.setLabel("תאריך סיום:");
        //Binder//
        binder.forField(subject).bind(Todo::getSubject,Todo::setSubject);
        binder.forField(dudate).bind(Todo::getDudate,Todo::setDudate);
        binder.forField(taskstatus).bind(Todo::getTaskStatus,Todo::setTaskStatus);
        binder.forField(customerid).withConverter(new StringToLongConverter(""))
                .bind(Todo::getCustomerID,Todo::setCustomerID);
        //Binder//


        addButton.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
        addButton.setThemeName("primary");


        //Fields//






        todofields.add(subject,customerid,dudate,taskstatus,addButton);
        todofields.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.BASELINE);
        todoList.setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.BASELINE);
        todofields.getElement().getStyle().set("margin-left","auto");
        getContent().add(todofields,subjects,todoList,todogrid);
        Direction.set(Direction.RTL);

    }

    private void saveTodo() {

        service.update(todo);
    }

    private void updategrid() {
        List<Todo> todo = service.findAll();
        todogrid.setItems(todo);
    }

}
```

mainview.java

```
package com.packagename.myapp.spring;



import static com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.VaadinIcon.*;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, viewport-fit=cover")
@Theme(Lumo.class)
@Route
@PWA(name = "SimpleIT", shortName = "SimpeIT")
public class MainView extends AppLayout {
    public static final String ITM_DASHBOARD = "DashBoard";
    private Map<Tab, Component> tab2Workspace = new HashMap<>();

    public MainView() {
       Direction.set(Direction.RTL);

       // setPrimarySection(Section.DRAWER);
        Image img = new Image("https://i.ibb.co/KbZbtWm/SimpleIt.png", "Vaadin Logo");
        img.setHeight("75px");
        addToNavbar(new MenuBar(), img);
    Tabs menu = new Tabs(dashBoard()
            ,customers(),Todo(),Tickets());
    menu.setOrientation(Tabs.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        menu.addSelectedChangeListener(event -> {
            final Tab selectedTab = event.getSelectedTab();
            final Component component = tab2Workspace.get(selectedTab);
            setContent(component);
        });
        addToNavbar(menu);
        this.setPrimarySection(Section.NAVBAR);
        setContent(new Span("click in the menu ;-) , you will see me never again.."));





    }
                         ///**// Tabs Area//**///
    private Tab Tickets() {
        final Span label = new Span("קריאות");
        final Icon icon  = BOOK.create();
        final Tab  tab   = new Tab(new HorizontalLayout(icon,label));
        tab2Workspace.put(tab, new TicketsView());
        return tab;
    }


    private Tab customers() {
        final Span label = new Span("לקוחות");
        final Icon icon  = BOOK.create();
        final Tab  tab   = new Tab(new HorizontalLayout(icon,label));
        tab2Workspace.put(tab, new CustomersView());
        return tab;
    }

    private Tab dashBoard() {
        final Span label = new Span("ראשי");
        final Icon icon  = DASHBOARD.create();
        final Tab  tab   = new Tab(new HorizontalLayout(icon,label));
        tab2Workspace.put(tab, new DashBoardView());
        return tab;

    }

    private Tab Todo() {
      final Span label = new Span("משימות");
      final Icon icon = DASHBOARD.create();
      final Tab tab = new Tab(new HorizontalLayout(icon,label));
      tab2Workspace.put(tab,new TodoView());
      return tab;

    }
                            //**//Ends Of Tab Area//**//
}
```

TodoService.java

```
package com.packagename.myapp.spring.Services;


import com.packagename.myapp.spring.Todo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class TodoService {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public List<Todo> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT ID, UserID, notesID,TaskStatus FROM todo",
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Todo(rs.getLong("ID"),
                        rs.getLong("UserID"), rs.getLong("descriptionID"),rs.getString("taskstatus")));
    }

    public void update(Todo todo) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO todo (TaskStatus,dudate,subject,CustomerID) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",todo.getTaskStatus(),todo.getDudate(),todo.getSubject(),todo.getCustomerID());


    }

}
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.packagename.ui.views.TodoView.saveTodo(TodoView.java:119)
    at com.packagename.ui.views.TodoView.lambda$new$259424d1$1(TodoView.java:52)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:441)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:441)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:378)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:359)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:301)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:87)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1540)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:246)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: Why did you comment out `updateGrid()` in the button clicklistener?

Comment: If you have error messages, then please add them to the question (location, stacktrace etc).

Comment: May you add the stacktrace as well may you provide a brief instruction how to recreate your error?

Comment: @KasparScherrer I just check something. I delete the comment out it's not working.

meaby it's related to my Todoservice? I didn't use it on my TodoView ?

Comment: @cfrick i add the errors

Comment: @pikkuez I put data on the form, and then click add button, and I used the writebean to create my todo object . and then use the saveTodo method to insert data into the SQL

Comment: Your service is not injected. See https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-routing.html

Comment: ... but how does `saveTodo()` not throw a nullpointerexception if service is not injected?

Comment: @cfrick i still dont understand how to inject it from the link you have add, can you try to explain? (i am just 1 month in this vaadin/java language)
and thank you all for the time you take to answer my questions.

Comment: @Snirbenyosf the same like you did with the jdbcTemplate in the service. Add `@Autowired` in front of it

Comment: Don't use field based injection.  Add it to the constuctor in your view as described here https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-routing.html#using-dependency-injection-and-spring-autowiring

Comment: can you explain what is @Autowired? what it's job? try explain it to melike i am 7 years old :)

Comment: your select query in `TodoService::findAll` seems strange. you select the columns `ID, UserID, notesID,TaskStatus` but from the resultset you use `ID, UserID, descriptionID, taskstatus`.

Comment: @KasparScherrer yes i fixed it.
i add Autowired still nullpointer Error. :( i dont get what i am doing worng

Comment: >  you explain what is @Autowired? what it's job? < This is a different question and already answered here or in the spring docs. Please take a look and see how far you come and if you face problems, create a new question.  The comments here are no forum.

Comment: @cfrick you right, i will read the docs again.
what does it mean "Don't use field based injection"? can you show me exmple from my code?

Comment: The last link i gave, shows the c'tor based injection (@Autowired in the c'tor arguments)

Comment: @cfrick i used it, but it not seems to work. well thank you for your help i will test untill i understand why its not working.

Comment: Then update your question with the changes and the (new) error you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was noticed already in comments you are not injecting nor initializing your service :

This is the only line you have in a `TodoView.java` and service here is null

```java
private TodoService service ;
```

And this is the reason you are getting NPE at

```java
private void saveTodo() {
        service.update(todo);
    }
```

since you are calling method on null

So a fast solution should be to add a

```java
 @Autowired
  private TodoService service ;
```

as you are using spring already

A similar example here at this article : [Spring @Autowired tutorial](http://zetcode.com/spring/autowired/)